# Consumer thread to consume N recs at interval

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice, producer-consumer

I am designing scenario where 5 Threads from `Executor` will publish to Queue1.
There is one consumer1 to this Queue which needs to consume 5K recs and go to sleep for 10 milli seconds and again same process.
This is needed because this consumer again will publish records to another queue Queue2 and I don't want to put load on the second Queue2.

How can I handle consumer1 so that it can process 5K records and sleep for 10 ms?

Plese note that Queue1 is unbounded queue like li med list as we don't want to block 5 producer if consumer is slow.
Also producer can process parallel instead of waiting for 5K reva and then drain in bulk. So I think if I use atomic counter then it would be ok.
There could be multiple producers in future but for now it's only one so I am using executor for producing too on safer side.
But is there any better API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implementation of `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` and drain up to 5K elements to your worker and then pause for 10 milliseconds:

```
  blockingQueue.drainTo(outputList, 5000);
  Thread.sleep(10);
  // Continue with your work
```

If there are not enough elements in the queue, you might be iterating too often. In that case you might want to do this:

```
  outputList.add(blockingQueue.take()); // thread will wait here for new elements
 
  if (outputList.size() == 5000){
       Thread.sleep(10);
      // Clear outputlist and continue with your work
  }
```

Comment: @Victoe, sorry but I didn't mentioned it's unbounded queue. I edited question for more clarity. And we don't have to wait for 5K. Here my thread will wait till 5K available. It can continue in short. Once 5K is done producer can take a pause.

Comment: Hi, that is fine, BlockingQueue are unbounded by default. Moreover, it is prepared to have several producers/consumer in parallel (it is concurrent and thread safe)

Comment: thanks! I would go with your approach.but I don't want that wait for 5K. Beacause if <5K then producer should not wait.

Comment: Then drainTo would be the best option IMHO

Comment: @Yoxi, kindly accept & upvote if this help you, thanks!